# Pandas: Conditional replace on consecutive rows within a group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to build "episodes" from a list of transactions organized by group (patient).  I used to do this with Stata, but I'm not sure how to do it in Python.  In Stata, I would say something like:

```
by patient: replace startDate = startDate[_n-1] if startDate-endDate[_n-1]<10
```

In English, that meant to start with the first row of a group and check if the number of days between the `startDate` of that group and the `endDate` of the prior group was less than 10.  Then, move to the next row and perform the same thing, then the next row... until you'd exhausted all rows.

I have been trying to figure out how to do the same thing in Python/Pandas and running into a wall.  I could sort the dataframe by patient and date, then iterate over the entire data frame.  It seems like there should be a better way to do this.

It's important that the script first compare row 2 to row 1 because, when I get to row 3, if the script has replaced the value in row 2, when I get to row 3, I want to use the replaced value, not the original value.

Sample input:

```
Patient    startDate    endDate  
1          1/1/2016     1/2/2016  
1          1/11/2016    1/12/2016  
1          1/28/2016    1/28/2016  
1          6/15/2016    6/16/2016  
2          3/1/2016     3/1/2016
```

Sample output:

```
Patient    startDate    endDate  
1          1/1/2016     1/2/2016  
1          1/1/2016     1/12/2016  
1          1/1/2016     1/28/2016  
1          6/15/2016    6/16/2016  
2          3/1/2016     3/1/2016
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Comment: Adding input, desired output and what have you tried so far will get you places...

Answer (score 0):

I think we need `shift` + `groupby` , and `bfill` + `mask`  is the key

```
df.startDate=pd.to_datetime(df.startDate)
df.endDate=pd.to_datetime(df.endDate)

df.startDate=df.groupby('Patient').apply(lambda x : x.startDate.mask((x.startDate-x.endDate.shift(1)).fillna(0).astype('timedelta64[D]')<10).bfill()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True).fillna(df.startDate)
df
Out[495]: 
   Patient  startDate    endDate
0        1 2016-01-28 2016-01-02
1        1 2016-01-28 2016-01-12
2        1 2016-01-28 2016-01-28
3        1 2016-06-15 2016-06-16
4        2 2016-03-01 2016-03-01
```